# Creating new column based on multiple possible cell possibilities across several columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, multiple-columns, data-analysis

`` data[, allkneePR := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `==`, "0082")), .SDcols=PR1:PR3] ``

Hey, I'm trying to look for different diagnoses c("0082", "0083", "0084") across a range of rows and columns in data.table (the dataset is huge). If one of the values is "0082" or "0083" or "0084" in any of the columns PR1:PR3 I want another column that indicates true. Right now this works with the above code, but I am trying to add in multiple diagnoses, not just "0082". I tried the any() function which doesn't work, and just using a vector c("0082", "0083", "0084") doesn't work.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Fun practice dataset is here:

```
data <- as.data.table(data.frame(PR1 = c("0081", "0082", "0083", "0084", "8154"), PR2 = c("12","0084", "1","3", "9"), PR3 = c("9", "12", "25", "0083", "8154")))

data[, allkneePR := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `==`, "0082")), .SDcols=PR1:PR3]
data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==` for comparing a vector of length greaterr than 1

```
library(data.table)
data[, allkneePR := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, 
               c("0082", "0083", "0084"))), .SDcols=PR1:PR3]

data
#    PR1  PR2  PR3 allkneePR
#1: 0081   12    9     FALSE
#2: 0082 0084   12      TRUE
#3: 0083    1   25      TRUE
#4: 0084    3 0083      TRUE
#5: 8154    9 8154     FALSE
```

If the columns are character, can change `%in%` to `%chin%`

Comment: ```one[, allkneePR := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, any("0081", "0082"))), .SDcols=PR1:PR15]``` Running this on my actual dataset gets me the error: "coercing argument of type 'character' to logical". Thoughts on how I can fix that?

Comment: @davidk Have you created allkneePR column as a character class earlier.  If that is the case, when updating with `:=`, it would have that error.

Comment: allkneePR is empty at the moment. I am creating a new column with that name with a certain value if "0082" or "0083" etc are found in any of the columns PR1:PR3 for a particular row, is the general idea

Comment: @davidk  the error happens when `dt <- data.table(col1  = 1:5); dt[, col1:= letters][]`

Comment: @davidk Can you do `one[, allkneePR := NULL]`, then before assigning check  `one[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, any("0081", "0082"))), .SDcols=PR1:PR15]` and see if there are any suspicious cases.  Here, I am assuming that your columns are `character` class

Comment: Hmm, I just get Error: unexpected '|' in "one[, Reduce(|". I am successfully able to do everything I need to on one column using the following, but it doesn't work on multiple columns from what I have seen: ```[, knee_PR1 := apply(three[,"PR1"], 1, function(r) any(r %in% c("0081", "0082", "0083")))]
```

Comment: @davidk, I think the backquotes around `|` and `%in%` got lost in the comments

Comment: I get all False in the output if I use table() and the error coercing argument of type 'character' to logical when running the code you give above with the backticks

Comment: @davidk I can only reproduce the error if I have created the column before with a different class.  If you have never created the column, then that error is strange