# Error debugging for data.table production of logical vector

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns, data-analysis, assign

`` one[, allkneePR := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, any("0081", "0082"))), .SDcols=PR1:PR15] ``

This is related to a previous question I asked: [Creating new column based on multiple possible cell possibilities across several columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61047460/creating-new-column-based-on-multiple-possible-cell-possibilities-across-several/61047485#61047485). The above code works on the practice data.table but yields "coercing argument of type 'character' to logical" error when I run the code on the actual dataset. Do I need to change the classes of my columns, or is there a better more efficient way to address this? My dataset has millions of rows. Thanks!!

Class of PR columns is character at the moment.

Practice data.table:

```
data <- as.data.table(data.frame(PR1 = c("0081", "0082", "0083", "0084", "8154"), PR2 = c("12","0084", "1","3", "9"), PR3 = c("9", "12", "25", "0083", "8154")))

data[, allkneePR := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `==`, "0082")), .SDcols=PR1:PR3]
data
```

Comment: I noticed you changed your operator from `%in%` to `==`. Why not just use `%in%`? Too slow?

Comment: Both work for a single observation like "0082" but only %in% works for multiple. I am primarily using %in% at this point. No real difference in speed that I noticed between them

Comment: `data[(allkneePR)]` does work on the data that you have shared, right?. Does it give you an error on your actual data?